# Replicating the Excel MAXIFS function in r + dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My data look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
Source <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))
ID <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X3")
Treatment <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
Measure <- rnorm(n = 6, mean = 10)
df <- tibble(Source, ID, Treatment, Measure)
df
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Source ID    Treatment Measure
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A      X1            0   10.2 
2 A      X2            0    8.86
3 A      X3            1   11.3 
4 B      X1            0   10.4 
5 B      X2            0    9.70
6 B      X3            0   10.9
```

What I want is, a variable that has the same length as `Treatment`, but takes the value 1 if *any* ID under a given source has treatment = 1, and 0 if not. Similar to the MAXIFS() function in Excel, which would give what I want by putting this into a cell:

```
=MAXIFS([Treatment], [Source], [@[Source]])
```

But I need it in dplyr, for reasons related to the complexity of the IRL version of my example data, which is much bigger and more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this question all written and ready to post before I realized the solution is trivially easy with `ungroup()`:

```
fixed_df <- df %>%
  group_by(Source) %>%
  mutate(Treated = max(Treatment)) %>%
  ungroup()
fixed_df

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Source ID    Treatment Measure Treated
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A      X1            0   10.2        1
2 A      X2            0    8.86       1
3 A      X3            1   11.3        1
4 B      X1            0   10.4        0
5 B      X2            0    9.70       0
6 B      X3            0   10.9        0
```